# Появление div после заполнения определенное количство символов в input

Tags: javascript, php, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы к примеру человек ввёл определенное количество символов и вывелся новый , если он удалил символы в input то  исчез. Заранее спасибо, нужно на js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}

.input-code:valid~.div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="input-code" pattern='.{5}' name="code" placeholder="Code" required>
  <div class="div">Some block</div>
</form>
```